# Is it possible to create a standalone Quick Look extension/plug-in?

Tags: xcode, macos, preview, quicklook, macos-app-extension

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/719/#:%7E:text=Quick%20Look%20provides%20API%20to,and%20videos%20with%20the%20QLPreviewController.) we should new build **Thumbnail** or **Preview Extensions** instead of the old **Quick Look generators** which will be deprecated (probably in *Big Sur*).

There is also no Option to create a `Quick Look plug-in project` in *Xcode* anymore. Instead you need to create an application that contains a quicklook extension `target`.

My question is: Can I not create a **standalone** Quick Look extension (or plug-in) anymore to preview files without a useless wrapper app that fulfils no purpose? Has anyone tried or found out if this is still an option?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you figure anything out with regards to this? Looks like some quicklook plugins are not working on Big Sur.

Comment: Unfortunatrly standalone QLPlugins no longer work with Big Sur as these were deprecated in favor of the new App Extensions API.